# get the image stream of the camera

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently developing a windows phone 8.1 Silverlight in C#. I managed to get the stream of the camera and output it on the screen of the phone (using PhotoCamera). This app is about OCR so I need to get an image very frequently to perform operations on it (the goal is to detect a specific object but through the camera and not a picture). Does anyone have an idea about how to achieve that (-> a function from the API that sends you an image every so often)? There is a lot of Microsoft tutorial, but I can't find one about that particular usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this seems to be the tutorial I was looking for. Hopefully this will help other people with the same problem : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/hh202982(v=vs.105).aspx .